# Matrix Algebra Hint

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find an an example of a $2\times2$ matrix $B$ where $B^2=0$ and has no zero entries.

This seems like a ridiculously simple problem but I have been looking at it for awhile and coming up with blanks. Helpful hints to nudge me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writing down a general $2\times 2$ matrix and squaring it:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&b(a+d)\\c(a+d)&bc+d^2\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Can you see how to choose non-zero $a$ and $d$ to make two of the entries $0$? Once you’ve done that, choosing non-zero $b$ and $c$ to make the other two entries $0$ isn’t hard.

Comment: Or just reallze you want the minimal polynomial to be $x^2$, which must be the characteristic polynomial, so $ad-bc=0$ and $a+d=0$.

Comment: @Thomas: I’m not willing to assume that the OP knows about characteristic polynomials yet.

Comment: Yeah, that was why I put it as a comment, rather than my own answer :)

Comment: thank you thank you, this has been incredibly helpful to me. I believe I went wrong when I assumed the square of a matrix merely consisted of squaring its entries...

Comment: @Alex: You’re very welcome. Yes, that notion was wrong; matrix multiplication takes a little getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

$$\left(\begin{array} {ccc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1\end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You need the range space to lie in the null space.

One simple collection to start looking at is dyads of the form $A=u v^T$. (Then
$\ker A = \ker v^T$, if $u \neq 0$ and ${\cal R} A = \operatorname{sp} \{u\}$, if $v\neq 0$.)

In this case, you want $A^2 = 0$, so you need $v^T u = 0$, and also
you want all entries of $u,v$ to be non zero.

For example, $u=(1,1)^T$, $v=(1,-1)$.

Another approach is to look at the Jordan form $J$. From this you see that both eigevalues are zero, and there **must** be a one in the upper right.
Now look for $V$ such that $V J V^{-1}$ is all non-zero.